# Buttons not at the same place in Android and iOS

Tags: react-native

I have buttons that are not located at the same place in iOS and Android.
In Android they are at the middle bottom of the screen (it is what I expect) but in iOS they are at the top of the screen.

Do you know how I can put buttons in iOS at the same place as Android ?

```
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements'; 
...
<ImageBackground
    key={`image${i}`}
    source={{uri: image}}
    style={{ width: deviceWidth, justifyContent:'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}></View>
      <Text style={{flex: 1}}> {textToDisplayEnglish[i]} </Text>
      <Button
             title={textA[i]}
             style={{flex: 1}}
             type={typeButton[i]}
             onPress={() => this.triggerAction(i)}
      />
      <View style={{flex: 1}}></View>
</ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have too many `flex:1`. It'd be best to avoid using too many of them,unless you need to. try something like this:

```
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements'; 
...
<ImageBackground
    key={`image${i}`}
    source={{uri: image}}
    style={{ width: deviceWidth, justifyContent:'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1 }}>

      <Text> {textToDisplayEnglish[i]} </Text>
      <Button
         title={textA[i]}
         type={typeButton[i]}
         onPress={() => this.triggerAction(i)}
      />

</ImageBackground>
```

hope it helps!